# How should I choose between "while verb+ing", "when verb+ing", and "verb+ing"?

Tags: meaning, legalese, participles

First sentence:

> (**While being** || **Being**) a good person, he (*devoured* || *had been devouring*) kittens.

In this sentence I mean that he was always a good person in the past, not only while devouring kittens.

Second sentence:

> (**While using** || **When using** || **Using**) the services, (*you
>   agree* || *you're agreeing*) to our terms.

I have seen every of above variants in real agreements as well as "by using ..., you're agreeing". What the difference?

Third sentence:

> We follow these rules (**while providing** || **providing**) the
>   services.

That means that "we" follow these rules throughout the time we provide the services. Also, is it correct to say "*during providing*"?

Fourth sentence:

> (**While being** || **Being**) the main instrument for resolving such
>   issues, this law must be applied.

So, this law has always been the main instrument for resolving such issues since it entered into force, it is not only for a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must keep in mind is that "while" doesn't only carry the literal meaning of "during a period of time".

For example, the first sentence would read completely differently depending on whether you use "while" or not.

"Being a good person, he devoured kittens" means that he devours kittens because he's a good person. Compare, for example, "Being stubborn as always, he disagreed with us" - it means that he disagreed with us because he was stubborn.

"While being a good person, he devoured kittens" means that the person is generally good, but despite that they devour kittens. Compare "While being stubborn as always, he could see our point" - he was still stubborn, but despite that he agreed to something.

---

In the second sentence, "while/when" might technically be correct, but it reads awkwardly - something like "you agree to our terms as long as you're using the services". I'd rather use "by using" here - meaning that "starting to use the services carries an implicit agreement to our terms".

---

In the third one, "during providing" is ugly - you generally avoid two -ings in a row. Otherwise, I think both are fine, though "while providing" reads better to me personally.

---

The fourth is a bit similar to the first - the meaning flips when you apply "while" to the sentence. So either this low must be applied *because* it's the main instrument etc. (without "while"), or *despite* that (with "while").